# mouse position using c

Tags: c++, c, mouse

As part of a small app I am working on, I need to find a way to return the coordinates of the mouse on the screen when I click. I am looking for a solution that would run the same across operating systems, or at least the same on Unix systems. I'm wondering if there's a low-level solution for this. I have seen solutions implemented in Java, C#, and Python, but they all involve using a larger framework.

Comment: Have you tried using GTK frameworks?

Comment: I rigged up a temporary solution for my Ubuntu environment, which used the Python GTK tools and Tkinter. Basically, I created an invisible frame that covered the whole screen, and then detected the mouse position on that invisible frame. @phyrrus9

Comment: Take a look at this example program: http://www.gtk.org/tutorial1.2/gtk_tut-23.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using Qt. The problem is that, you will have different windowing systems on different platforms, potentially even on Linux.

As a fallback, you could check how Qt gets this bit right across the platforms, and copy/paste that into your software. It might bring further dependencies into your software.

gtk is also an option, but it might not be a cross-platform solution such as Qt or wxWidgets, or even FLTK. However, gtk is closer to your initial requirement, the C programming language.

Comment: It is important that no "invisible frames" or anything have to be made. When the program runs, I want it to return the position of the mouse on the screen (at the next click) regardless of what application is up. Is this possible in Qt?

Comment: Would QT allow to copy back? wxWidgets certainly doesn't have such restrictions. Anyway, I think this is not really as trivial as yo make it seem. ;)

Comment: On Linux-based systems you can safely use libX11 because it is the de facto window system. The pointer position has nothing to do with neither qt nor GTK (even if they would have some abstraction for controlling it).

Comment: Jocke, it would be a strage idea to restrict it to libX11 :) when it has to be cross-platform. Note, the wayland development has also been progressing. Furthermore, there are people using framebuffer, and so forth. Such abstraction is somewhat complicated, and if any, I think Qt may be the best bet, but then again, it is not C, and someone would need to rewrite those bits.